# How to return html or json from ViewSets depending on client django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I've created an APIs endpoints for mobile developers with all of the logic there. Now I need to create a web version of this app. Is it possible to not write the views specifically for this, but use already existing one in APIs?
In API I am using Django Rest Framework ViewSets.
Assume that this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then this is going to be my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

viewsets.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .models import Post

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', viewsets.Post, base_name='post')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I've seen this [HTML & Forms](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-html) in docs, but if I put renderer_classes and template_name it just renders html with the parameters that I want, but I want to have a separate endpoints for just returning json for mobile developers and rendering a user-friendly html for web version. Is it possible to do this and if it is, how do I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to manually create a separate endpoint to handle HTML requests, but you can easily achieve this using [Template Renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer)

Comment: What the point of doing this? My project is much bigger than presented and I think this is a very bad idea to just copy and paste a thousands lines of code adding to them renderer_classes

Comment: According to your question you require separate endpoints for mobile and desktop. Django follows the MVC architecture where a view is just a callable to a URL. If you were using a normal view you can check if a request is AJAX but i am not sure that can be achieved using django rest framework.